# How to configure/enable libvpx config file for x64-win64-gcc in cygwin?

Tags: gcc, cygwin, webm, vp8, libvpx

User@DESKTOP-H6N1GOG /cygdrive/c/libvpx

$ ./configure --enable-unit-tests

enabling unit_tests

enabling vp8_encoder

enabling vp8_decoder

enabling vp9_encoder

enabling vp9_decoder
Configuring for target 'x86-win32-gcc'

enabling x86

enabling runtime_cpu_detect

disabling avx512: not supported by compiler

Neither yasm nor nasm have been found. See the prerequisites section in the README for more info.

Configuration failed. This could reflect a misconfiguration of your
toolchains, improper options selected, or another problem. If you
don't see any useful error messages above, the next step is to look
at the configure error log file (config.log) to determine what
configure was trying to do when it died.

How can i target build with x64 with cygwin? I am using Cygwin in windows 10.

Comment: Have you tried to install `nasm` ?

Comment: No i am not tried it. Actually i am follwing this doc of libvpx SDK https://github.com/webmproject/libvpx/.. I have successfully used step 4 source ../libvpx/tools/set_analyzer_env.sh address. then configure showing the error above. Seems its configured for x86 but i need to configure for x64.